# Neo4j Return Top Level Nodes in Tree

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following data in Neo4j:

```
CREATE (t1:T {start:1, end:8})
CREATE (t2:T {start:1, end:4})
CREATE (t3:T {start:1, end:2})
CREATE (t4:T {start:3, end:4})
CREATE (t5:T {start:5, end:6})
CREATE (t6:T {start:7, end:8})
CREATE (t2)-[r1:T_OF]->(t1)
CREATE (t3)-[r2:T_OF]->(t2)
CREATE (t4)-[r3:T_OF]->(t2)
CREATE (t5)-[r4:T_OF]->(t1)
CREATE (t6)-[r5:T_OF]->(t1)
```

This creates a tree with start and end values, which in my actual application are epoch dates. I want to be able to find the nodes that don't have shorter/smaller nodes attached to them in a given range.

```
MATCH (t:T)
WHERE t.start >= 1 AND t.end <= 6
(MAGIC)
RETURN t
```

My goal is for this to only return `t2` and `t5`, even though `t3` and `t4` fall in the range. Since they have a `T_OF` relationship to `t2`, they should be ignored.

I've tried a few different ways, but unfortunately I can't figure this one out.

Please let me know if I should explain better.

Comment: What do you mean by "shorter/smaller nodes", and what is the importance of the `T_OF` relationship?

Comment: In the actual application, these are Terms of a school year. You have the top term, SchoolYear, and the sub-terms Semester 1 and Semester 2, with smaller terms of Quarter 1-4, and even smaller Periods withing the Quarters. The idea, for example, is to return the terms within a range, without including the subterms. For example, get Quarter 1, but not the periods underneath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

It collects all the `T` nodes with the right date range, and then filters out all the nodes that have a `T_OF` relationship to any node in the collection.

```
MATCH (t:T)
WHERE t.start >= 1 AND t.end <= 6
WITH COLLECT(t) AS ct
RETURN FILTER(x IN ct 
  WHERE ALL (y IN ct 
    WHERE NOT ((x)-[:T_OF]->(y))))
  AS result;
```

Comment: Exactly the idea I was looking for but not familiar enough with collection stuff to figure out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use paths as expressions and also negate them.

```
MATCH (t:T)
WHERE t.start >= 1 AND t.end <= 6
AND NOT (t)<-[:T_OF]-()
RETURN t
```

Comment: Using what you posted, I was returned `t3`, `t4`, and `t5` instead of `t2` and `t5`.